# UITextView character limit count is incorrect with emoji

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, emoji

I have an issue with my UITextView character limit where the count double, triple, or quadruple counts emoji. I want emoji to count as 1 character, the way they do in the Twitter iOS app. Here is the code I have in my `shouldChangeTextInRange` method

```
let characters = textView.text.characters.count + (text.characters.count - range.length)
        if characters <= self.characterLimit {
            // update character limit label as we type
            self.characterLimitLabel.text = String(characters) + "/" + String(self.characterLimit)
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
```

What should I change to produce the proper result when accounting for emoji?

Comment: Have you ever seen those new emojis with different skin colors on an older phone? It actually comes up as the old emoji with the standard skin color AND a square with the color palette of the new skin color. I believe that is why its counting them as multiple characters

Comment: Oh ok, is it possible to fix the character count on those? Maybe count the user's keystrokes on the keyboard instead of the actually textView character count?

Comment: Explain `text` and `range` vars? (first line)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's going to be an easy solution... You will have to check the unicode values to see if each character is an emoji. You will have to hard code those cases, and then you will have to update them every time new emojis are released. My recommendation is that you should just forget about emojis costing more characters... If you want more information, there's a github repo that can check for emojis pretty simply.. but then again, it may become outdated (if not already outdated).

https://github.com/woxtu/NSString-RemoveEmoji

Comment: I actually saw that Twitter's app also has the issue with skin colors and stuff. It's okay I'll leave it as is. Thanks

Comment: Not sure how much it is related to the question, but this one: https://github.com/ericdke/WithOrWithoutEmoji isn't outdated at all (disclaimer: it's mine).

Answer (score 1):

Use **NSString length** instead of **String count**

```
    let newString: NSString = currentString.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: text) as NSString
    let characters = newString.length
    if characters <= self.characterLimit {
        // update character limit label as we type
        self.characterLimitLabel.text = String(characters) + "/" + String(self.characterLimit)
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
```